# Is there is some change in google maps v2 api key access

Tags: google-api

My google maps api v2 don't show the map. I checked even on v3 also can't see the map. I am getting this  :  http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/0/intl/iw_ALL/main.
I checked the api key and try to define a new key. the same problem occure.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem for a few days.
I finally got a way to solve it temporarily.
GoogleMaps has released a new version (3.19) the 17th of February.
You can force your pages use the previous version (3.18), which is unchanged, by adding in the javascript parameters the version :

```
<script language="JavaScript"
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://maps.google.fr/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=fr&v=3.18">
```

With the 3.18 version, maps are correctly displayed.
We have now to find what we have to change to make the 3.19 version work !

Comment: hi Pep. thanks a lot. In ver 3 it is helpfull. however My Sites ar in ver 2.

Comment: Hi pep until 17/02/2015 everything worked perfectly in ver 2. Maybe this new version destroyed everything. My mail is gilad@ladpc.net.il. Maybe we can discuss this issue. Thanks a lot